# Limiting Python file space in memory

Tags: python, file, memory

When you open a file in python (e.g., open(filename, 'r') does it load the entire file into memory? More importantly, is there a way to partially load a file into memory to save memory space (for larger systems) or am I overthinking this? Particularly, I'm trying to optimize this in a cloud environment where I only need ~1-2 lines of a large file and would prefer not inputting all of that into memory as we pay for computation time.

General question, nothing was tested. looking for opinions and such

Comment: It will only load into memory if you read from it. You can use `f.readline()` to load one line at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add any more arguments into the `open()` function, but you can change how you read the lines from the file. For example:

```
# open the sample file used
file = open('test.txt')
  
# read the content of the file opened
content = file.readlines()
  
# read 10th line from the file
print("tenth line")
print(content[9])
  
# print first 3 lines of file
print("first three lines")
print(content[0:3])
```

You could also use the `file.readline()` method to read individual lines from a file.

Although this still means that your entire file will be read into memory, this is a compressed version of the full file, so doesn't take up the same amount of space as the full file in memory.

Comment: Interesting, do you know how much it ends up loading? I always thought it loaded all of it into memory but did reduce CPU time due to accessing less of the file.

Comment: @JustinRomeo `f.readlines()` will load all lines into memory. If you want to search for a specific line, you should make a loop that uses `f.readline()` without the `s`

Comment: The specifics depend on the size of file, along with number of lines (more lines mean a larger file object, even if less text is inputted), in turn taking up more memory. I would say it decreases the size at least by 50%, as the function only returns an iterable object.

Comment: Also `f.readline(7)` wont load the 8th line. It will read a single line with a maximum of 7 bytes

Comment: would a regEx like re.findall(r'some pattern', f.readlines()) be more optimal?

Comment: @jrjustin if memory is an issue you shouldn't be using `readlines`

Comment: Yes, regEx would be more optimal if you didn't mind about loading the entire file into memory, which the `readlines` method does, i.e. if you had a lot of memory to spare.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I guess I was trying to imagine a way regEx could pull from a file but it would def either load the whole thing or check line by line with f.readlines()

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure how you would be able to search for an individual word or phrase in a file without loading the entire file into memory, which then defeats the purpose. But as far as the `open()` function is concerned, not much memory is used until you iterate over each of the lines.